# Creating a view dynamically via a variable - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am in the process of attempting to create a SQL Server view based upon a query dynamically using a variable.

I have written and tested the query and can confirm it works with the results. I have attached a link to Imgur to view the screenshots as I am unable to post the full query due to reasons.

Creating the view, however, I am receiving a few errors and can't seem to work them out! I have checked over the query multiple times and re-structured my code in creating the view.

```
declare @MarketingCampaignID int,
        @viewQuery nvarchar(max)

set @MarketingCampaignID = 246159

if exists(select * from sys.views 
          where name='vwCampaign_' + cast(@MarketingCampaignID as nvarchar(255)) + '_FlatValueTable')
begin
    set @viewQuery = 'drop view XMPieTracking.vwCampaign_' + cast(@MarketingCampaignID as nvarchar(255)) + '_FlatValueTable'
    exec (@viewQuery)
end

set @viewQuery = N'Create View XMPieTracking.vwCampaign_' + cast(@MarketingCampaignID as nvarchar(255)) + '_FlatValueTable'
set @viewQuery = @viewQuery + N'SELECT * FROM (...)

exec( @viewQuery)
```

See images:
[image: image source : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCvDe.jpg]

image source : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCvDe.jpg

Comment: Implicit type conversions are never your friend. Sprinkle in some `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), 'drop view ...') + `. The fact that `@viewQuery` has that type does not mean T-SQL feels compelled to convert intermediate strings. (And always, always use `PRINT` to inspect dynamic queries before executing them; diagnosing syntax errors is virtually impossible otherwise.)

Comment: It would be helpful to see that actual `@viewQuery` that is failing.  Please try to break it down to as little code as possible to show the problem (I see that you've collapsed around 130 lines of the dynamic SQL).

Comment: Also, just in case: consider if this problem isn't better solved by either a stored procedure or a table-valued function that takes a `@MarketingCampaignID`. If your clients have no support for parameters, dynamically creating a view that calls out to a table-valued function (or a small set of these functions) is still far simpler than repeating the entire definition in each view. (This wouldn't work if you have one of those awful designs where *everything*, including table names, is dynamic -- consider recasting those as properly normalized tables, possibly partitioned.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have utilised the PRINT you have recommended me. The print seems to output only "Create View XMPieTracking.vwCampaign_246159_FlatValueTable". So I am thinking it's something to do with the line after.

Answer (score 0):

```
set @viewQuery = N'Create View XMPieTracking.vwCampaign_' + cast(@MarketingCampaignID as nvarchar(255)) 
               + N'_FlatValueTable AS'  --Add `AS` here
set @viewQuery = @viewQuery + N' SELECT * FROM (...)
                                ^-- Add a space here
```

And add the `AS` keyword before the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: I've tried to implement what you've provided me but it doesn't seem to be working!

Comment: The message displayed is "Incorrect syntax near 'as'.".

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to be rude but why not use a stored procedure instead of a view?

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_stored_procedures.asp) you can see the detailed information about stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks for the help but this NEEDS to be a view.

Comment: Sorry @KIZZ ! Good luck finding a solution.